# 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method

Tags: linq, frameworks, entity

'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

I am getting the error I wrote above in the code below. Can you help me?

```cs
foreach (DataRow r in dtToplamTutar.Rows)
{
    var urun = db.TbAlisDetay.Where(x => x.StBarkodNo == r["StBarkodNo"].ToString())
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.InAlisDetayId)
        .Take(1)
        .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: string StBarkodNo = r["StBarkodNo"].ToString();

                        var urun = db.TbAlisDetay.Where(x => x.StBarkodNo == StBarkodNo).OrderByDescending(p => p.InAlisDetayId).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: That's how I did it. Thanks